# Rotate list items

Tags: html, css, navbar

I would like to make my navbar [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hCM5.png), but after rotating text, vertical text gets too far away from horizontal, any help?

```css
  .vertical {
    float:right;
    writing-mode:tb-rl;/*IE*/
    writing-mode:vertical-lr;/* OPera/webkit*/
    writing-mode:sideways-lr;/* should be the one */      
  }
  .horizontal {
    float:right;
    line-height: 0em;
    
      
  }
  li {
    display:inline-block;
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="horizontal">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><i class="far fa-circle"></i></li>
    <ul class="vertical">
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: expected visual]

Comment: hello. insert your code pls

Comment: padding:0 to the nested ul

Comment: you can't nest `ul` like that. The nested `ul` must be **inside** an `li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might not need imbricated `ul` .

you may use `display:grid` *(or `display:inline-block` +`float` if that is not an option)*  and eventually `shape-outside` if content has to wrap around :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 15%, 75% 15%, 75% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  /* requires a floatting element */
  margin-left: 1em;
  /* here clip-path + background shows the shape  to wrap around*/
  background: black;
  color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 15%, 80% 15%, 80% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: end;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 0.5em 0 1em 1em;
}
ul li:nth-child(3){
padding:0.5em;}
ul li:nth-child(3)~li {
  grid-column: 3;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  /* should be enough now-days*/
  padding:0 0.5em 1em;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}

p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #bee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <ul class="horizontal">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="far fa-circle"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- random text to show wrapping effect -->
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus
  enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus
  enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus
  enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus
  enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
  luctus, metus</p>
```

If grid is not an option, float can do too :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 15%, 80% 15%, 80% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  background: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 15%, 80% 15%, 80% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}

ul {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  width:min-content;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}

ul li:nth-child(3)~li {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav>
  <ul class="horizontal">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="far fa-circle"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- random text to show wrapping effect -->
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus
  enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus
  enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus
  enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
  luctus, metus</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus
  enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis
  luctus, metus</p>
```

Comment: @DenisKviatkovskij  which words ??  there's  `word-spacing` for the text or is it  in between links ?

Comment: Between words in the list and make them closer to the circle itself. I tried word-spacing but I could make spacing bigger but not smaller

Comment: @DenisKviatkovskij , I have edited the first snippet and modified padding values of lis , see if you can tune it to your needs ;)